# SCILAB console unable to perform "exec" command

Tags: scilab

I am trying to execute a `.sce` file in the `SCILAB` console but, when i type the command:

`exec("hello world.sce")` the console presents:

```
--! error 241"
File "hello world.sce does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to type in the whole path of the file, e.g. on a Windows machine something like this:

```
exec("d:\Scilab\hello world.sce")
```

And it's usually safer NOT to use any space or non english characters (e.g. é, ö, ñ) in the file name or in the folder names. Some machine will handle it correctly, some other not at all! So after renaming the file you may call like this:

```
exec("d:\Scilab\hello_world.sce")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in your present working directory? Check with `pwd` if you're in the directory you expect and do `ls` to list all files.

It might also be the space in the filename, but not sure.